# Storing a checkbox value from an object in Localstorage and retrieving it again

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, local-storage, lodash

So I have a list of items with checkboxes, and I'm hiding and showing them based on the checkbox value.  For instance, at the start, all if the items are checked which means that their visibility is set to true.  If I uncheck, it's set to false and they're hidden.  This list is in a modal which acts as a "filter this list" feature.

What I'm trying to do however, is set the values to localstorage and then when the user refreshes, the filters that they have applied remain.

I can't send a working fiddle here unfortunately but I can apply some partial code.
I'll try to explain it the best I can;

```
volumeFilter(symbol, visible) {
            const self = this;
            this.marketFiltersStorage[symbol] = this.marketFiltersStorage[symbol] || {};
            lodash.forEach(self.volumeData, (obj, objKey) => {
                if (symbol === obj.name && self.volumeData[objKey].visible === true) {
                    self.volumeData[objKey].visible = false;
                    this.marketFiltersStorage[symbol].visible = self.volumeData[objKey].visible;
                } else if (symbol === obj.name && visible === false && self.volumeData[objKey].visible === false) {
                    self.volumeData[objKey].visible = true;
                    this.marketFiltersStorage[symbol].visible = self.volumeData[objKey].visible;
                }
                localStorage.setItem('marketFiltersStorage', JSON.stringify(this.marketFiltersStorage));
            });
        },
```

So `VolumeFilter` is what triggers when I check/uncheck the checkbox.  `marketFilterStorage` is the object I created to hold the values in localstorage.  `volumeData` is the object that holds all of the items.

The logic here `if (symbol === obj.name && self.volumeData[objKey].visible === true)` is me setting the item's visibility to true or false

What I was trying to do, is loop through each item and for each condition, add the true/false to the localstorage, seen here; `this.marketFiltersStorage[symbol].visible = self.volumeData[objKey].visible;`

This is kind of working, but when I refresh, the localstorage remains, but when I try to check or uncheck another checkbox, it rewrites again.

Long story short, I just want to add the `visible` value to local storage and then pull it in again when the page reloads.  I haven't got the `getItem` implemented yet

I'm so sorry if that's a lot to take in.  If you have any questions, I'll be more than happy to try and explain it more clearly.

Thank you so much for any help in advance

Comment: Are you using lodash? If so ad the tag.

Comment: yep, sorry, missed that one.  thanks!